# Ignoring date column from Group By in Sql Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want select date column value from table but don't want group by by date.
Is it possible.
as i want to group the data by using other columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gin.GoodsIssueNoteNumber,gini.GoodsIssueNoteItemNumber, 
                sp.OrgPath,ISNULL(gini.IssuedQuantity,0) as 'Quantity', 
                gin.MRN, sp.SpareName,sp.SysId as 'spareid',
                stc.StoreName,sp.ItemGroupName,sp.PartCode,
                SUM(stc.StockCount) as stockCount,
                SUM(stc.TotalInventoryValue) as StockValue,
                ISNULL(gini.Cost,0) as WeightedAverageItemCost,
                ROUND (gini.IssuedQuantity * gini.Cost,2) as 'TotalIssued Cost',
                gin.Date as 'GIDATE'
FROM vwSpare sp         
INNER JOIN vwGoodsIssueNoteItem gini 
  on sp.SysId=gini.Spare 
INNER JOIN vwGoodsIssueNote gin 
  on gin.SysId in (SELECT AssociatingId FROM GoodsIssueNoteAssociation 
                   WHERE AssociatedId=gini.SysId and IsActive=1)    
LEFT JOIN vwStock stc 
  on stc.Spare=sp.SysId and stc.GoodsIssueNoteId is not null 
 and gin.StoreIDName=stc.StoreName
WHERE IsRepairable=0 and Scrap=0 and Repaired=0 and sp.IsActive=1  
  and gin.IsActive=1 and gin.Date > DATEADD(mm,-6,GETDATE()) and gini.IsActive=1 
GROUP BY sp.SpareName,stc.StoreName,sp.OrgPath,gini.IssuedQuantity,gin.MRN,
         sp.SysId,sp.ItemGroupName,sp.PartCode,gini.Cost,
         gin.GoodsIssueNoteNumber,gini.GoodsIssueNoteItemNumber,gin.Date
```

I don't want gin.Date in group by

Comment: If you don't want to group by it, what value would you like to select for `GIDATE` since it can have multiple values? Removing `GIDATE` from the select list should allow you to remove it from `GROUP BY` also.

Comment: As a side note, specifying _both_ `DISTINCT` **and** `GROUP BY` is usually not correct; `GROUP BY` by definition will create a distinct tuple for the columns listed in it (and since aggregate functions reduce to one result...).

Answer (score 4):

SQL requires that all non-aggregate fields be in the `GROUP BY` clause.  However, you can do this:

```
SELECT b.ungroupedColumn,  -- your ungrouped columns
       a.* -- your grouped columns
FROM (SELECT Column1, Column2, sum(Column3)
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY Column1, Column2) a
INNER JOIN mytable b ON a.Column1 = b.Column1
```

The idea is that you bring back your grouped data, minus the extra column, and then join those results back to your table to add the ungrouped columns.

Here is an example, assume I have the following inventory of produce:

```
Type       Name       Qty
---------- ---------- -----------
Fruit      Apple      1
Fruit      Orange     2
Fruit      Banana     3
Vegetable  Carrot     4
Vegetable  Cucumber   5
Vegetable  Peas       6
```

I can run the following query:

```
SELECT b.[Name],
       a.*
FROM (SELECT [Type], sum ([Qty]) as Qty_Of_Type
      FROM Produce
      GROUP BY [Type]) a
INNER JOIN Produce b ON a.[Type] = b.[Type]
```

It will bring back the following results:

```
Name       Type       Qty_Of_Type
---------- ---------- -----------
Apple      Fruit      6
Orange     Fruit      6
Banana     Fruit      6
Carrot     Vegetable  15
Cucumber   Vegetable  15
Peas       Vegetable  15
```

Comment: You can do this with a regular `(INNER) JOIN` - I'd be _extremely_ surprised if there was nothing for the join.

Comment: @RogerRouse - Just so we all know, this is an ineffecient approach. I just learned it from my answer for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198681/remove-resultset-duplicates-based-on-three-columns

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is that you can not do it. You can not fetch the columns that are not present in the `GroupBY`

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned before, technically this **can not be done**. However, for practical purposes - If you don't want to use this date column in the `group by` clause and still want to display it in result set, one option is to use `max()` or `min()` function over your date column. In many practical purposes this will solve the problem.

But in many other cases, this will silently inject a bug in your code to be detected much later. If the date column repeats the same value across all the records of a specific group - the above solution will work perfectly. But if the dates are different across the record set under a same group, `max()` or `min()` will produce an incorrect result.